# Stripe Connect: Cancel Subscription with Node.js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm building a platform on Stripe Connect and I'm entirely confused about how to cancel accounts created through it. The [Connect docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#creating-subscriptions) really only obliquely mention canceling subscriptions and I've followed the description in the [core documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#canceling-subscriptions) but I'm getting a `Customer X does not have a subscription with ID Y` error despite copying both of those values from dashboard (and, obviously, using them to create the subscription in the first place. I've seen a bunch of questions about the RoR side of this but all of the fixes I've found seem to be specific to that API. I know I could just delete the customer and it would end up in the same place but there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay that was quick. This is just on me not taking a logical leap in the docs and some incomplete information on the node side :(

While you create subscriptions with ids from your side you actually cancel them with the subscription id that's found in the callback (`[charge].subscriptions.data[0].id`) when a user signs up for the plan. Once you've got that stored you can just use the suggested general code without any Connect-specific changes

```
stripe.customers.cancelSubscription(
  customer_id,
  subscription_id,
  function(err, confirmation) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);
```

customer_id will look something like this `cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
while the subscription_id will look something like this `sub_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Will leave this here because I couldn't find anything on it and hopefully it helps someone else out.